# Middle and Old English Corpora Distributable Under Open Source License

Tags: corpora, resource-request, old-english

I'm working on an open source computational linguistics project, and I need Old and Middle English corpora that I can distribute along with the software. Most of the corpora that I've been able to find are all under license, and even the Middle English Compendium seems to only be accessible through their web interface. Are there any resources out there that I'm missing?

Comment: Here is a list of corpora you could take a look at:
http://www.uow.edu.au/~dlee/corpora.htm

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately these all appear to be under a restrictive license of some sort :(